# .htaccess on multisite and roots theme?

Tags: php, multisite, themes, theme-roots

i install the Roots Theme and then convert my installation to multisite... so that wordpress add some code into the previous .htaccess with root settings.

My .htaccess now looks like this and i'm becoming something redirection errors

Is there a conflict into my .htaccess?

```
##### Multisite Htaccess #####
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

##### Multisite Htaccess end ####


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On   
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/roots/css/$1 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/roots/js/$1 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/roots/img/$1 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I have both roots and multisite. However, I do not have roots specific rewrite rules.

I have the vanilla rewrite rules defined in the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration). I use the ones for subdomains instead of subfolders.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comparing them to yours, perhaps, the bottom block is extra?